# does Enthought Python distribution includes pyhdf and HDF 4

Tags: python, image-processing

In Enthought Python Distribution, I saw it includes pyhdf and numpy. Since it includes pyhdf, does it also include HDF 4?

I am using pylab to code at this moment.

Because I want to use a module of the pyhdf package called pyhdf.SD. And it Prerequisites HDF 4 library. So do I still need to install HDF 4 if I want to use pyhdf.SD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the versions of EPD that include `pyhdf`, you don't need to install `HDF 4` separately.  However, note that `pyhdf` is not included in all versions of EPD---in particular, it's not included in the 64-bit Windows EPD or the 64-bit OS X EPD, though it is in the 32-bit versions.